# Proper syntax for Ionic observable => function?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working on an application that, among other things, displays a Google Map with numerous differently colored markers placed all over, utilizing data drawn from a .json file. These markers designate what is at the coordinates (for the purposes of this, I'll call them `Type 1`, `Type 2`, `Type 3` and `Type 4`.

On a Settings page, there are four `<ion-toggle>` components corresponding to each type. I've put the Types into a json file like so:

types.json

```
{
"types": [ 
    {"name": "Type 1", "enabled": true},
    {"name": "Type 2", "enabled": true},
    {"name": "Type 3", "enabled": true},
    {"name": "Type 4", "enabled": true}
        ] 
}
```

Now, here is some of my other code:

```
public types: any;
public places: any;

getPlacesAndTypes(): Observable<any>{
return Observable.forkJoin([
  this.http.get('./assets/data/rawdata.json').map(res => res.json()),
  this.http.get('./assets/data/types.json').map(res => res.json())
  ]);
}

ngAfterViewInit() {

// Gets json file and prepares to create markers
this.plt.ready().then(() => { this.getPlacesAndTypes() 
  .subscribe(
    data => {
    this.places = data[0];
    this.types = data[1]; 
  }) => this.initMap(this.places, this.types);

  }

);  
}
```

However, I'm having trouble with the last part. When I try to run it, I keep getting this error (highlighted object is marked with **):

```
  typescript: src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 49 
        ';' expected. 

  L48:          this.types = data[1]; 
  L49:        }) **=>** this.initMap(this.places, this.types)
```

Like most syntax errors, doing what the console suggests doesn't actually seem to be the answer. Can anyone help me with the proper syntax for this? This has been bugging me for a week now.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? `then(() => {}) => foo()` doesn't make any sese. Do you know what is `=>`?

Comment: What I expect to happen is for `this.places` and `this.types` to get passed to the function `this.initMap()` after `.subscribe` is done. I was hoping someone could help me with achieving that, since I'm a little new at Ionic and TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it like so:

```
this.plt.ready().then(() => { 
  this.getPlacesAndTypes().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.places = data[0];
        this.types = data[1];
        this.initMap(this.places, this.types);
      }
    );
}
```

This waits for the platform ready event then subscribes to your Observable and when the success callback (data) arrives calls your `initMap` function with the data from the callback.

Comment: It seems to be a start, but I'd like to set `data[0]` and `data[1]` into `this.places` and `this.types` before doing `initMap()`. I can't have duplicate identifiers.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, you can just add it inside the callback!